# How to use Typhoeus::Request object using https

Tags: ruby, http, ssl, https, typhoeus

I'm trying to make an `https` request using the `Typhoeus::Request` object and i don't get it working.

The code i'm running is something like this:

```rb
url = "https://some.server.com/"
req_opts = {
 :method => :get,
 :headers => { 
      "Content-Type"=>"application/json",
      "Accept"=>"application/json"
  },
 :params=>{},
 :params_encoding=>nil,
 :timeout=>0,
 :ssl_verifypeer=>true,
 :ssl_verifyhost=>2,
 :sslcert=>nil,
 :sslkey=>nil,
 :verbose=>true
}
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url, req_opts)
response = request.run
```

The response i'm getting is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://some.server.com:443/
Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2019 02:25:05 GMT
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have libcurl built with OpenSSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's hard to know because your example is not a reachable url.  But 2 things I see is that you are not passing an ssl cert or key.  But also 302 indicates a redirect.  You can try to follow redirection but your first problem is probably you don't need to set SSL options, why are you?

See if you try the following options:

```
req_opts = {
 :method => :get,
  :headers => {
    "Content-Type"=>"application/json",
    "Accept"=>"application/json"
   },
    :params=>{},
    :params_encoding=>nil,
    :timeout=>0,
    :followlocation => true,
    :ssl_verifypeer=>false,
    :ssl_verifyhost=>0,
    :verbose=>true
  }
```

See the following sections for more info

https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#following-redirections
https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#ssl

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for responding now. The url i was testing is https://staging.node.skycoin.net/api/v1/version. I tried the configuration you gave me but i get the same answer with code 302.

Comment: @CarlosBermudez Not sure why.  I just ran this code locally with the url you provided and I get code 200.  Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a redirect as I tried it also without `followlocation` and get same result.